# Getting exeption when sending variable via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Getting an error when trying to delete a user from db.
Here is the code that i wrote:
This is server side:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeRestController {

   @DeleteMapping( value = "/delete_user")
   public List<Employee> deleteEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "id") Integer id) {
       employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
       List<Employee> list = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
       return list;
   }
 }
```

Client side:

```
function delete_row(id){
    $.ajax({
        type:'DELETE',
        url:'/delete_user',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:JSON.stringify({
            id:id
            }),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Error from server side :

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present]
```

Error code from client side is 400

I am noob at ajax , javascript and spring. Sorry if the problem is obvious and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try serializing the json

Comment: You're not sending a query param named `id`. What you have is a request body that contains a JSON object that contains a key called `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried this

```
function delete_row(id){
$.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/delete_user",
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    
                }
            });
}
```

or directly bind to url

```
function delete_row(id){
$.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/delete_user?id="+id,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using PathVariable instead of RequestParam.

```
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete_user/{id}")
   public List<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
       employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
       List<Employee> list = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
       return list;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work when theirs doesn't?